# MySQL field type for date in the format YYYYMM

Tags: mysql

I have a date that I am wanting to store in a MySQL database in the format YYYYMM.

I am trying to decide on the best field type to use, am I right in thinking that the DATE field type is no good in this situation because it expects the format to be YYYY-MM-DD?

Would VARCHAR be the best choice in this instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [size of each data type in MySQL](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30885&seqNum=7).

`DATE` is only 3 bytes. It also allows you to instantly use all of the [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/date-and-time-functions.php)

`VARCHAR` is string length + 1 byte

Comment: So DATE would be a more efficient choice.  It expects the format YYYY-MM-DD though so I am not sure it would work for this case?

Comment: It should be more efficient and functional than a `VARCHAR`. Is there a particular reason you want to store the data as YYYYMM?

Comment: It is pretty easy to convert it to the `DATE` format using string manipulation, but if size and function aren't a major consideration it may be better to use `CHAR` or `VARCHAR`.

Here's some code to help:
    `SET @input = "201601";
    SET @test_date = (SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@input, 1, 4), "-", SUBSTRING(@input, 5,6), "-01"));
    SELECT DAY(@test_date);
    SELECT DATE_ADD(@test_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY);`

Comment: +1 for the `DATE `approach. It's so easy to convert between DATE and String, and you get a lot of functionality for free by using DATE